# How to open a pull request for an issue on my main branch "without merging"

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Disclaimer: I am a beginner to Git so forgive me if parts of the question do not make sense.

A company I applied for sent me a programming assessment.

The assessment page has a link which created a private repository on my GitHub (a repo that I own, not a forked repo). The created repo has an open `issue` about the new features they want me to implement, which I have implemented.

They then say that I need to make a "**pull request (without merging)**" with my changes before I press the submit button on the assessment page. However, I thought pull requests were only for forked repositories, so how do I do a pull request on my own repository? I tried to fork the repository but couldn't. I also tried to open a pull request against an old version of the branch, but I need to commit my solution for this to work, which I am afraid to do because I could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can make a pull request against your own repository. When they say "without merging", I think they mean just don't push the merge button. You definitely can commit - it won't automatically merge. Commit to your new branch, open pull request, just don't push "merge pull request".

Comment: @PressingOnAlways When you say "commit to your new branch" do you mean create a new branch and commit to it? I tried committing to the existing branch and still can't do a pull request

Comment: Whenever you push a new branch to the repository you will see a `Compare & pull request` button or you can go to `Pull request` tab and press `New pull request` and choose the source and target branch. Whenever your pull request is created you can still commit and push it to the source branch and it will also avaible in pull request and whenever your team is ready to accept the changes just press `Merge pull request` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the responses. I created a new branch to which I committed the code. Once I did that, I got a pull request option, as the comments here noted.

Answer (score 4):

"Pull requests" are a GitHub feature, not a Git feature.  Git does not have Pull Requests—not the GitHub style ones, anyway.  (Bitbucket, like GitHub, has pull requests, which they call "pull requests", and GitLab, like Bitbucket and GitHub, has pull requests, but they call them "merge requests".  So PRs are very common on Git *hosting sites*, for reasons that become obvious once you start using the hosting sites.)

The tricky bit here is that a pull request ("PR") made *from* yourself *to* yourself has no obvious reason for existence.  The reason any PR (of any of the three flavors mentioned above) *exists* is because these three systems support what they call *forks*.  Forking a repository is much like cloning a repository, with two small differences that add up to be quite large.  You make a PR exists *because you made a fork*.  The PR allows you to communicate with the owner of the *other repository*, with a lot of convenience and some nice features.  But if you didn't make a fork in the first place, there is no "other repository": the only person around to communicate with is yourself.  That's kind of silly.<sup>1</sup>  Can't you just ask yourself your own questions and tell yourself your own stories?  Still, the fact that it's easy to make a PR to "the other guy"—the owner of some other repository that you've forked—makes it trivial to make a PR to yourself.

To see what this is all about, let's start with an overview of Git itself.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't necessarily true within a larger organization, such as a company.  GitHub, at least, currently have some limitations here that act as barriers to use of forks within some organization—so sometimes we will use an organization's repository and make pull requests "to ourself", where "ourself" means "someone else who works for FooCorp and has the same access to the same repository", for instance.

---

#### Git is a *Distributed* Version Control System

Git is used as a [Version Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) System or VCS.  Such systems have a pretty long history and a lot of practical knowledge and usefulness behind them.  Until the Internet became widely available, though, most version control was *centralized:* there was some master server (or server-like entity) that maintained the versioning, and you would just extract some files or some version, work on it, and then send updates back to the master control system or site.  These *centralized* VCSes (CVCSes) offer a bunch of features, but have a bunch of drawbacks.  So people invented [*distributed* version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control), where no single person or entity has *the* "source of truth" version.  Instead, everyone has, or can get, *every* version.  A DVCS (distributed VCS) can be used *like* a CVCS: one simply points to one of the copies and says "that's the central one".  But a CVCS cannot be used as a DVCS, since the key feature of a DCVS is that there *is no* "the" repository: all repositories are equal, or at least potentially equal (with everything depending on how you *use* them).

Anyway, being a "D"-style "VCS", everyone using some Git repository will have, or can have, every version.  To make this work, a Git repository itself consists, at its heart, of two big databases:

- One big database holds *commits* and other Git support objects.  Each commit holds a version of the project: a *snapshot* of every file, plus some *metadata* holding information such as the name and email address of the person who made the snapshot.  Git stores all this stuff as objects in the objects database.

  There's an annoying limitation with this database.  Every object *in* it is found by some big, ugly, random-looking *hash ID*.  Hash IDs are very difficult for humans to use.  We are just plain bad at hash IDs.  But Git *needs* the hash IDs to access the objects in the database.  So...
- A second database—usually much smaller—holds *names*, such as branch and tag names, and maps each name to one hash ID.  Git cleverly arranges things so that if a *branch name* holds the *latest* hash ID, Git can use that to find *every commit "in" or "on" that branch*.  (Git's use of branches here is weird, compared to the way branches work in most other VCSes, but we don't have to address that here, and won't.)

The *objects* database is read-only: once you create some object in it, you can't *change* that object (at all, ever).  The *names* database is read/write: you can add and remove names at will and you (or more normally, Git) can stuff whatever hash ID is appropriate into whatever name is appropriate, at any time.  The normal progression is to *add a new commit* to the big database, and then update one *branch name* in the little database to remember the latest commit.  The latest commit itself remembers what *was* the latest commit's hash ID, which is how Git can then find earlier commits.

To make this useful on *your* computer—e.g., on a laptop where you'll build and test your change—you also need a *work area*.  A normal Git repository provides one work area, which Git calls the *working tree*.  A hosted Git repository—as on GitHub for instance—doesn't; Git calls such a repository a *bare* repository.  Because there's no work area, it's literally impossible to do any work directly on these hosted systems.<sup>2</sup>  You won't normally deal with bare repositories, *except on these hosted systems*.

---

<sup>2</sup>GitHub, at least, have since added some fancy methods to allow limited amounts of work directly on GitHub.  Because they start with a bare repository (where you *can't* do work), these systems are kind of weird and klunky, with peculiar limitations.  They "do work" by making temporary arrangements to get work done, doing the work, committing, and then tearing down the temporary arrangements, and this gives rise to all the weird limitations.  You should not try to get all your everyday work done this way: it's only good for certain limited uses.

---

#### Clones

Now, suppose someone else—Fred, or Lakeesha, or whoever—has an existing repository, and you want to do something with the software.  You don't need to mess with his or her copy of everything!  You just *clone* the repository.  He or she gives you read-only access, and you point your Git to their system and say *copy everything*, using `git clone`.

When you use `git clone`, what you get is a *new Git repository:* a pair of databases, plus a work area.  The databases are initially *totally empty*, but the cloning process *copies every commit* from the other Git, to populate your commits-and-other-objects database.

The slightly peculiar thing about `git clone` is that it *doesn't* copy all their *names*.  Instead, it copies their *tag* names as-is (usually), but take each of their *branch* names and *changes* them.  What were their *branch* names—branches `main` and `develop`, say—become your *remote-tracking names*, `origin/main` and `origin/develop`.  Basically your Git shoves `origin/` in front of each of their names.

The reason for this change-of-names is so that *you* can have *your* branch names, and you can use the *same names* they're using, but remember different "latest commit" hash IDs.  Git itself needs, and will use, the hash ID.  You'll want *your* Git software, working in *your* repository, to remember *your new commit*, once you make one.  They want *their* Git software, working in *their* repository, to remember *their* latest commit.

Giving you *your own* branch names, and letting them have *their* own branch names that can be different from yours and/or hold different hash IDs, makes this work.  So your clone initially has *no branches at all:* your Git copies their *branches* to your *remote-tracking names*.  (Remember, Git itself doesn't actually *need* branch names.  Git only *needs* the hash IDs.  The *names* are mostly just for humans.)

Once you have this clone, though, your Git will do one last step: it will *create* a branch name.  You get to choose which name to create, but most people running `git clone` don't bother.  In this case, your Git (your software working with your repository) asks their Git (their software working with their repository): *What branch name do you recommend?*  Git calls that the *default branch*, and on GitHub, this is usually `main` now, although in the past it was usually `master` (and many old repositories cling to the old traditions).

Now that your Git has a branch name, your Git finds which commit *their* branch name means, and creates *your* branch of the same name so that *their* latest commit is also *your* latest commit.  Then your Git *checks out* this branch, meaning it chooses this "latest commit" as the commit you'll be working with / on.  Your Git populates your working tree from this particular commit, and now you have files you can work with / on.

#### GitHub "fork"

Suppose someone Out There On The Net has a repository that you like, that you want to use and maybe even contribute to.  If this repository exists *on GitHub*, GitHub give you a convenient way to do this.<sup>3</sup>  You navigate, in a browser, to the repository, and then use a button labeled <kbd>FORK</kbd> to make a GitHub-side clone that's owned by *you*.  Because this is a clone, you need only *read* permission to make it.

What's special about this GitHub-side clone is this:

- GitHub do it in a way that's extremely low-cost for them (by avoiding almost all actual copying).
- GitHub *make a connection* from your clone back to the repository you forked.  **This enables easy pull requests** (the topic I'm addressing, even if it doesn't seem like it ).
- Last—and important for your use in just one moment—GitHub copy *all their branches* at the time you press the <kbd>FORK</kbd> button.  They can do this in part *because* they don't give you a working area, but also because they *only do this once*.  If you want your GitHub-fork clone's branches updated, *you* have to do that from now on.  This is in my opinion a bit of a flaw in the way GitHub do this, but it's not a *big* problem.  You just need to be aware of it.

So, once you've pressed <kbd>FORK</kbd> (and filled in a few blanks as needed), *you* have a repository on GitHub now, that's a clone of the original repository, with added features.  And now you can get to work.

---

<sup>3</sup>If not, GitHub give you nothing at all—at least not yet.  It's to GitHub's advantage, then, to attract more users to GitHub, so that *you* will be attracted to GitHub, because their repositories will be *on* GitHub, giving you an advantage if you put yours on GitHub too.  Then *your* repositories will be on GitHub, attracting still more users, and the GitHub network grows.  If and when you hit some limitation, you may be inclined to start paying GitHub for services.  The same reasoning applies to Bitbucket and (to a lesser extent because their focus is a bit different) GitLab.  In economics, this is called the [network effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect).  It explains *why* GitHub are willing to give you a certain amount of "free" goodies: it winds up making GitHub's owners richer, or at least they certainly hope it does.

---

#### You now clone your fork

In general, you can't do good work directly on GitHub.  (As I remarked in footnote 2 earlier, until relatively recently you couldn't do *any* work directly.)  So your next task is to clone your fork to your laptop.  This could be any computer, but I'll just say *laptop* to make it clear *which clone we're talking about:* there is one clone on your laptop, while there are *two* on GitHub: your fork, and the repo you forked.  So we have:

- your repo on your laptop: that's your new clone, with *one* branch;
- your fork on GitHub: that's your other new clone with *all* branches; and
- their original repo.

In your clone on your laptop, you do your work, using laptop-specific branch names.  Typically you might create a new branch name, then make a new commit or two.  Then, to send these *new commits*, you run:

```
git push -u origin my-new-branch
```

This has your Git (your software working with your laptop repo) call up "their" Git (GitHub's software working with your fork).  The two Git software implementations have a conversation that, while it uses branch names to get bootstrapped, is all about *hash IDs*.  Your laptop Git finds out which new commit(s) you've just added, that your GitHub fork still lacks, that your laptop Git must send to their Git to put in your GitHub fork.

Your Git now packages up these commits (you see messages about "counting" and "compressing" and "writing objects").  The commits and other objects go over the network and arrive at GitHub.  GitHub stick them in a temporary quarantine area and then look at your request, which reads:

- Please, if it's OK, create or update the branch name `my-new-branch` in your repository (*i.e., in your GitHub fork* ) so that it remembers the same commit as my branch name `my-new-branch` remembers in my (*laptop*) repository.

Since your GitHub fork doesn't have this branch name at all yet, they accept the polite request.  They create that name, and now your GitHub fork has a new branch, with these new commits (one or two or however many) on it—and, since Git is weird, it also has all the old commits on it too: Git branches always go all the way back to the beginning of time.<sup>4</sup>  Git*Hub* will usually cleverly present this to you as "just two commits", and when used in certain ways, Git itself will show things this way too.<sup>5</sup>

**And now, at long last, the pull request stuff kicks in.**  Having made this new branch *in* your GitHub fork, you can now use a single button click (and maybe a lot of typing—it's a good idea to type some stuff in too...) to send, to the *original repository owner* on GitHub, a "Pull Request" that asks them—the original repository owner, the person who owns the repo that you forked—to please incorporate the work you did into *their* repository.

How, and whether, they choose to do this incorporating, and if so when, is all up to them.  What GitHub will do is send them email and/or generate some other kinds of notices (Slack, tweets, whatever) so that they *become aware* of the PR.  GitHub provide, for both them and you, ways that you and they can communicate: you'll get email and/or Slack messages and/or whatever else as they ask questions, if they choose to ask questions, or make comments, if they choose to make comments.  GitHub will send you notices if and when they accept or reject your PR.  Depending on how active they are, you may hear back from them almost immediately, or not for months: that part is up to them.

If and when they choose to incorporate your new commits, they can do that with as little work as one click.  That makes it easy for them to take your work back.

You can probably see the value proposition here.  They don't have to let you *change* their repository at all, but they can let you *propose changes to* their repository.  They can take them as is, or ask you to make some adjustments to them, or make the adjustments themselves.  Collaboration becomes easy.  That's the, or a, *raison d'être* for GitHub (and other hosting sites): they take the power of Git—the *distributed clone*—and turn it into something *easier to use*.  (Git is notoriously difficult to use, and using Git to collaborate *without* using GitHub or something similar is, well, why GitHub and GitLab and Bitbucket exist.)

---

<sup>4</sup>It's possible to create branches that *don't* go back to the first commit in the repository, but usually that's not what you want to do.  It makes things harder later.  Be sure you understand enough of the graph theory behind `git merge` before you do this.

<sup>5</sup>Whether that's "right" (or what you want, really) depends on what you want.  It's a good idea to learn the bits of theory alluded to in footnote 4 soon.

---

#### Your situation

In your case, they are not giving you a repository to fork.  You're supposed to create your own repository, then clone it and work *as if* you had forked someone else's repository.  Then you're supposed to make a pull request *to yourself:* this is another "as if".  Then you're supposed to let them poke around in the GitHub repository you created, see your PR, and inspect both the code you wrote *and* the Git and GitHub etiquette you may have used in the process.

Normally, if you had a repository of your own on GitHub, and you had your clone on your laptop and did some work, you wouldn't *negotiate with yourself* about when, whether, and how to incorporate new laptop commits into the GitHub repository.  You'd just stick them in there yourself.  But if you did that, you would not get a chance to show off your knowledge of how to work GitHub PRs.

To learn the *mechanics* of actually *making* a Pull Request—i.e., where to navigate on GitHub and which clicky buttons to click—see [GitHub's own documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests), which is pretty good.